# XYSeriesCollection with two lines

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have problem with display data correctly. I am creating two series:

```
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Accumulated result");
            XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Index chart");
```

then in loop im adding data to each series: series.add series1.add

```
            XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
            dataset.addSeries(series);
            dataset.addSeries(series1);


            JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Simulation", // Title
                    "Days", // x-axis Label
                    "Cumulative results", // y-axis Label
                    dataset, // Dataset
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // Plot Orientation
                    true, // Show Legend
                    true, // Use tooltips
                    false // Configure chart to generate URLs?
                    );
```

And the result of creating chart is not satisfactorily, as it looks like: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6gBF.jpg
Do You see blue line? The second series will never have values more than 100 and in the chart looks like a straight line. Moreover i would like to have a legend for second series on the right side. Is any way to fix it?

Comment: what do you expect when you plotting two chart with values in range (-5k,60k) and (0,100)?

Comment: sorry i am using jfreechart first time, i am expect that two values will match with itself, so first value will have legend on left side second on the right side.

Comment: i missed one think, the x series is the same for both series.